# Chrome opens with "Data;" adress with selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, chrome-web-driver

When I'm starting the test I see 'data:,' in the chrome address bar and then nothing happens (the program doesn't continue) instead of starting navigating to the url.
I am using: chrome=55.0.2883.75 chromedriver=2.25 selenium=3.0.1 platform=Win64

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("facebook");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='btnK']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Facebook - Log In or Sign Up")).click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("u_0_n")));

        String expectedTitle = "Facebook - Log In or Sign Up";

        assertEquals(expectedTitle,driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the new ChromeDriver exe (2.26). Download [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.26/). You can see in the [notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/notes.txt) that 2.25 suppose to support Chrome 55 but there were bug fixes so try the latest.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm working on a [maven plugin](https://github.com/best-est/maven-web-drivers-compatibility-plugin) for these cases... I still have a lot of work to get it done properly...

Comment: Hi, i am using the same Chrome version, along with ChromeDriver 2.26. try to perform webdriver.manage().deleteAllCookies() will throw the following exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"4064.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}. this excetpion was thrown for previous versions of Chrome and ChromeDriver. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question with those details? I don't know about this issue, but you look for a specific issue in [ChromeDriver's issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list)